# MYSQL refuses remote connection with error "ERROR 2003 (HY000)" and TCP error 111

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have installed MySQL 8.0.25 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (ARM) instance on AWS.
I can access it using 127.0.0.1 address locally, but can't access it remotely from another instance.

"Bind-address" was commented out originally, I uncommented it and changed to "0.0.0.0" (mysql service was restarted) - didn't help, so I commented it back.
"Skip-networking" is not in the cnf file.

I changed the port to 3307 just to be sure that I'm looking at the right cnf, and now MYSQL does listen to port 3307:
[image]

locally I can connect using port 3307, but not remotely:
[image]

Here are the iptables:
[image]

I know that firewall works well, because if I remove port 3307 from the rules, the error is different:
[image]

As you can see, TCP error 111 ("Connection Refused") became error 113 ("No Route to Host").

Telnet connection is refused with the same error:
[image]

I've rebooted the MySQL instance - no change.

Why would MYSQL refuse remote connection, if "bind-address" is commented out, and firewall is open?

Comment: I only see it listening on 127.0.0.1, not 0.0.0.0.  If you're not binding to 0.0.0.0 it won't be accessible remotely.  When you set the bind address did your netstat change?

Comment: I don't see how your security group is set. Can you post that also?

Comment: @RodrigoM - Security group has ports 22, 3306 and 3307 open from any address. If SG were the problem, then closing the port in Ubuntu's firewall wouldn't have changed the TCP error from 111 to 113.

Comment: @stdunbar - when I change "bind-address' to "0.0.0.0" and restart MySQL, netstat still shows  "127.0.0.1:3307"  as Local Address, and 0.0.0.0:* as Foreign Address.                        https://i.imgur.com/zhiQkm0.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@stdunbar's comment pointed me in the right direction.

The problem happened because I followed the MYSQL installation instructions at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04 , and ran the security script while configuring MYSQL:

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

For some reason, this script causes MYSQL to ignore the `bind-address` setting in the cnf file, while it still uses the `port` setting - very confusing!

When I installed MYSQL without running the security script, the "local address" of the MYSQL daemon in the `netstat -lnp | grep mysql` command changed from 127.0.0.1:
[image]

to 0:0:0:0 :
[image]

After this, MYSQL started to accept remote connections.
Of course, I still had to create a remote user:

```
CREATE USER 'root'@'remotehostname' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'newpassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'remotehostname' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```